# Dapper Query(..): stream or loads all?

Tags: c#, orm, dapper

Does it load all records in this code or uses something like SqlDataReader?

```
using (var c = new SqlConnection(_options.TargetConnectionString))
{
    c.Open();
    foreach(var record in c.Query("select * from Users")) // suppose N+1 records
    {
        // all records loaded or read one by one here? 
        // some work here...
    }
}
```

Comment: consider using SQL Server Profiler to investigate this. But seems like all records are loaded in your case.

Answer (score 12):

Both options are supported. By default, the data is buffered into a `List<T>` on the basis that most queries are fairly small, and to avoid the "multiple recordsets" limitation. To obtain the underlying list without an extra allocation, use the provided `.AsList()` extension method. If, however, you want unbuffered data: pass `buffered: false`. This will give you an enumerator that wraps the raw `IDataReader` - suitable for huge queries.

Comment: I see. Another good answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026558/explanation-of-dapper-buffer-cache