# It is possible to stream a large SQL Server database result set using Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stream, dapper

I have about 500K rows I need to return from my database (please don't ask why).

I will then need to save these results as XML (more URGH) and the ftp this file to somewhere magical.

I also need to transform the each row in the result set.

Right now, this is what I'm doing with say .. `TOP 100` results:

- using Dapper's `Query<T>` method, which throws the entire result set into memory
- I then use AutoMapper to convert the database POCO to my FileResult POCO
- Convert to XML
- Then save this collection to the file system
- Then FTP

This works fine for 100 rows, but I get an Out Of Memory exception with AutoMapper when trying to convert the 500K results to a new collection.

So, I was wondering if I could do this...

- Stream data from DB using Dapper
- For *each row*, automapper it
- Convert to XML
- Stream result to disk
- <repeat for each row>
- Now ftp that file to magic-land

I'm trying to stop throwing *everything* into RAM. My thinking is that if I can stream stuff, it's more memory efficient as I only work on a single result set of data.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697509/what-does-the-buffered-parameter-do-in-dapper-dot-net

Answer (score 12):

> using Dapper's `Query<T>` method, which throws the entire result set into memory

It is a good job, then, that one of the optional parameters is a `bool` that lets you choose whether to buffer or not ;p

Just add `, buffer: false` to your existing call to `Query<T>`.

Comment: how does this change the code that executes this `Query<T> / QueryAsync<T>`? If it's not buffering, then how do i pull data out and process it row by row? or is there another trick?

Comment: @Pure.Krome in both cases, you *just `foreach` over the data* - it is an iterator block over the open reader. Note: if you don't want to use `foreach`, then you simply use `GetEnumerator()`, `MoveNext()` (checking the return value) and `Current` (remembering to dispose the enumerator at the end); `foreach(var x in y) {...}` is basically: `using(var iter = y.GetEnumerator()) { while(iter.MoveNext()) { var x = iter.Current; ... } }`

Comment: What is the suggestion now that Query<T> and QueryAsync<T> don't have a simple signature where you can add buffer: false?

Comment: @steve in the next "major" we're going to smash the API so that there is a List-T version (buffered) and an IAsyncEnumerable-T version (non-buffered). Right now, you may need to use the version that takes the command wrapper rather than just a string.