Enforce the use of Utf8JsonReader.ValueSequence for test purposes
I wrote my own BigIntegerConverter for JSON serialization/deserialization (.Net System.Text.Json)
In the Read method I checked if ValueSequence is used
...
string stringValue;
if (reader.HasValueSequence)
{
    stringValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reader.ValueSequence);
}
else
{
    stringValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reader.ValueSpan);
}

if (BigInteger.TryParse(stringValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var result))
{
    return result;
}
...

Now I want to test that code, but I am only able to get to the else tree so far. Based on the documentation I assumed that ValueSequence will be used if the data got big enough.
However, I already testing with BigIntegers as big as BigInteger.Pow(new BigInteger(long.MaxValue), 1234); and still cannot get the ValueSequence to be used.
Did I missunderstood something?
Is there a way to enforce the use of ValueSqeuence for test purposes?
My testcase looks like this
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(GetNotNullTestData))]
public void Read_EntityWithNotNullableBigInteger(string name, BigInteger expected, string value)
{
    // Arrange
    var json = $$"""{"Name":"{{name}}","NotNullableValue":{{value}}}""";
    // Act
    var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<NotNullableBigIntegerEntity>(json, _options);
    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    Assert.Equal(name, result.Name);
    Assert.Equal(expected, result.NotNullableValue);
}

Regards
Michael

From the documentation "For input data within a ReadOnlySpan, this always returns false. For input data within a ReadOnlySequence, this only returns true if the token value straddles more than a single segment and hence can't be represented as a span." I'm not quite sure what they mean with token values here but someone presumably knows.

Probably depends on the way the underlying stream is buffered. How are you feeding in the JSON?

@Charlieface I edited the question and added the test method.

Deserializing from a string is probably always going to use a single span, why wouldn't it? Now try it with a FileStream.

Utf8JsonReader has a constructor that takes a ReadOnlySequence<byte>, so you could take your JSON string, encode it to a UTF8 byte array, break that into small chunks, then convert that sequence of chunks into a ReadOnlySequence<byte> using ReadOnlySequenceFactory from this answer to Deserialize very large json from a chunked array of strings using system.text.json.
First, introduce the following factory class:
// From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61087772 to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079767/deserialize-very-large-json-from-a-chunked-array-of-strings-using-system-text-js
public static class ReadOnlySequenceFactory
{
    public static ReadOnlySequence<T> AsSequence<T>(this IEnumerable<T []> buffers) => ReadOnlyMemorySegment<T>.Create(buffers.Select(a => new ReadOnlyMemory<T>(a)));
    public static ReadOnlySequence<T> AsSequence<T>(this IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory<T>> buffers) => ReadOnlyMemorySegment<T>.Create(buffers);

    // There is no public concrete implementation of ReadOnlySequenceSegment<T> so we must create one ourselves.
    // This is modeled on https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.18/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/tests/BufferFactory.cs
    // by https://github.com/ahsonkhan
    class ReadOnlyMemorySegment<T> : ReadOnlySequenceSegment<T>
    {
        public static ReadOnlySequence<T> Create(IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory<T>> buffers)
        {
            ReadOnlyMemorySegment<T>? first = null;
            ReadOnlyMemorySegment<T>? current = null;
            foreach (var buffer in buffers)
            {
                var next = new ReadOnlyMemorySegment<T> { Memory = buffer };
                if (first == null)
                    first = next;
                else
                {
                    current!.Next = next;
                    next.RunningIndex = current.RunningIndex + current.Memory.Length;
                }
                current = next;
            }
            if (first == null)
                first = current = new ();

            return new ReadOnlySequence<T>(first, 0, current!, current!.Memory.Length);
        }
    }
}

Then write your converter e.g. as follows:
public class BigIntegerConverter : JsonConverter<BigInteger>
{
    // The actual implementation seems to be in INumberBase<TSelf>.TryParse() so I had to do this to call the method:
    static bool TryParse<TSelf>(ReadOnlySpan<byte> utf8Text, out TSelf? value) where TSelf : IUtf8SpanParsable<TSelf>, new() => 
        TSelf.TryParse(utf8Text, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out value);

    public override BigInteger Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.Number)
            throw new JsonException(string.Format("Found token {0} but expected token {1}", reader.TokenType, JsonTokenType.Number ));
        var utf8Text = reader.HasValueSequence ? reader.ValueSequence.ToArray() : reader.ValueSpan;
        if (TryParse<BigInteger>(utf8Text, out var value))
            return value;
        throw new JsonException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, BigInteger value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo), false);
}

Now you will be able to write your test method as follows, ensuring your input JSON is broken into small chunks:
public record NotNullableBigIntegerEntity(string Name, BigInteger NotNullableValue);

JsonSerializerOptions _options = new()
{
    Converters = { new BigIntegerConverter() },
};

public void Read_EntityWithNotNullableBigInteger(string name, BigInteger expected, string value)
{
    int byteChunkSize = 3;
    
    // Arrange
    var json = $$"""{"Name":"{{name}}","NotNullableValue":{{value}}}""";
    // Break into chunks
    var utf8json = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
    var sequence = utf8json.Chunk(byteChunkSize).AsSequence();
    // Act
    var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(sequence);
    var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<NotNullableBigIntegerEntity>(ref reader, _options);
    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    Assert.Equal(name, result?.Name);
    Assert.Equal(expected, result?.NotNullableValue);
}

Notes:

BigInteger implements IUtf8SpanParsable<BigInteger> which allows direct parsing from UTF8 encoded byte spans.  As such there's no need to call Encoding.UTF8.GetString() to construct a UTF16 string corresponding to the current value.

Based on the documentation I assumed that ValueSequence will be used if the data got big enough. -- maybe, maybe not.  MSFT seems to have intended ReadOnlySequence<byte> to be used when deserializing asynchronously from some request or response stream, but you are deserializing synchronously from an in-memory string.  Whether MSFT chooses to break that string down into a single UTF8 byte span or multiple UTF8 byte sequences is an implementation detail which they do not make public.
(When I check the reference source, the current code seems to convert the incoming string to a single byte span.)


Demo fiddle here.

I have to look into it. But the first try with just copy and paste your solution does not even call the .Read Method of the Converter class.

@IamanSwtrse - please add a [mcve].  I modified BigIntegerConverter().Read() to add a Console.WriteLine() and it is indeed being called, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kre0Qy.

Found it after 2 hours I did find a typo in the property name... :( Now it is working like a charm. Thanks
